# MPMusicPlayerController not behaving properly. IOS

Tags: nstimer, nsnotificationcenter, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am using `MPMusicPlayerController` to play 3 music files. My requirement is that after finishing first file, it should hold for given time interval and then play next music file. But it starts playing next file before it finish the first file.

Here is my code:

```
-(void) playMusic
{
    self.player.repeatMode = MPMusicRepeatModeNone;

    MPMusicPlayerController *controller = [MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer];
    MPMediaItemCollection *collection;
    if(self.counter == 0){
         collection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.firstItem, nil]];
        [controller setNowPlayingItem:self.firstItem];

    }else if(self.counter == 1){
        collection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.secondItem, nil]];
        [controller setNowPlayingItem:self.secondItem];

    }else{
        collection = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.thirdItem, nil]];
        [controller setNowPlayingItem:self.thirdItem];

    }
    [controller setQueueWithItemCollection:collection];
    self.player = controller;
    [self.player prepareToPlay];
    [self.player play];

}
```

This is what I am doing in notification methods:

```
-(void) nowPlayingNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if(self.counter == 0 && self.player.nowPlayingItem == self.firstItem){
        self.counter = 1;
        self.playerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(float)[self.defaults doubleForKey:SECOND_TIMER_VALUE_KEY] target:self selector:@selector(playMusic) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        NSLog(@"%f",[self.defaults doubleForKey:SECOND_TIMER_VALUE_KEY]);

    }else if (self.counter == 1 && self.player.nowPlayingItem == self.secondItem){
        self.counter = 2;
        self.playerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(float)[self.defaults doubleForKey:THIRD_TIMER_VALUE_KEY] target:self selector:@selector(playMusic) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        NSLog(@"%f",[self.defaults doubleForKey:THIRD_TIMER_VALUE_KEY]);
    }else{
        self.counter = 0;
        [self.player stop];
    }
}
```